# How do I set Ghidra to display static addresses in the listing view?

Tags: reverse-engineering, binaryfiles, hexdump, computer-forensics, ghidra

I'm doing static analysis on a binary in Ghidra. Ghidra displays the addresses of code and data in the listing view as the location where that item would be in memory if the binary were running, e.g. `0xffffffff811759d0`.

How can I instead set it to display the offset of that item within the binary file? In other words, I want the addresses displayed by Ghidra to match up with the addresses that would be displayed by `xxd`, which might be something like `0x0044fe40`.